# TypeScript error in /home/Documents/node_modules/cheerio-select/lib/index.d.ts(1,15): [0] ',' expected. TS1005

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, react-context, npm-run

Hello I am getting this error in terminal when i run npm run dev & npm run build in my terminal.

> [0] Failed to compile. [0]  [0]
> /home/Documents/frontend/node_modules/cheerio-select/lib/index.d.ts
> [0] TypeScript error in
> /home/fislam/Documents/frontend/client-dashboard/node_modules/cheerio-select/lib/index.d.ts(1,15):
> [0] ',' expected.  TS1005 [0]  [0]   > 1 | import { type Options as
> CSSSelectOptions } from "css-select"; [0]       |               ^ [0]
> 2 | import type { Element, AnyNode, Document } from "domhandler"; [0]
> 3 | export { filters, pseudos, aliases } from "css-select"; [0]     4
> | export interface Options extends CSSSelectOptions<AnyNode, Element>
> { ^C[1] INFO: Caught signal: SIGINT [1] [nodemon] exiting [1] npm run
> dev:server --silent exited with code SIGINT [0] npm run dev:client
> --silent exited with code SIGINT

Answer (score 2):

The issue for me was I was using an outdated version of cheerio. I fixed it by running

```
yarn add cheerio@latest
```

You can also try updating your TS to the latest version by running

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```